# SQL Server trigger for update inserted row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I want to create a trigger for this: I have two tables:

Table 1:

- `id` - integer - primary key
- `status` - integer - values: 1 for busy and 0 for available

Table 2:

- `id` - integer - primary key - autogenerated
- `id2` - integer - NULL or the value of an id from table1
- `status` - integer - values: 1 for working 0 for waiting
- `col1` - irrelevant column 1
- `col2` - irrelevant column 2
- `col3` - irrelevant column 3

and when the users does this

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (val1, val2, val3);
```

the trigger should check table1 and if it finds and available id (status = 0) it updates the inserted row table2.id2 = table1.id and table2.status becomes 1 otherwise table2.id2 remains NULL and table2.status becomes 0.

Now I've tried it many ways and I always get error messages.

This is my latest attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger 
ON table2
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 id 
                   FROM table1
                   WHERE status = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table2
        SET status = 0
        WHERE table2.id = Inserted.id
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SET status = 1
        WHERE table2.id = Inserted.id

        SET table.id@ = (SELECT TOP 1 id 
                         FROM table1
                         WHERE status = 0)
        WHERE table2.id = Inserted.id
    END
END
```

and errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure myTrigger, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.
>
> Line 17: set status = 1
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure myTrigger, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
>
> Line 22: where table2.id = Inserted.id

And if you feel generous the next thing I need to do is create a trigger that when a column is deleted from table2 it sets the status of the corresponding id in table1 to 0 (available)

I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your trigger, and a logic itself. You say you can have NULL in table2 ID column but it is PK with auto generated property...

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it  will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second statement is missing the update command:

```
    set status=1
    where table2.id= Inserted.id
    set table.id@ = (Select TOP 1 id 
                from table1
                where status=0)
    where table2.id= Inserted.id
```

Should be

```
    update table2 set table2.status=1,
           table2.id = (Select TOP 1 id 
                from table1
                where status=0)
    join Inserted as i
    on table2.id= Inserted.id;
```

This should fix your errors, however, your entire trigger could be refactored to be a bit cleaner, but that is outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: What about `where table2.id = Inserted.id`?

Comment: I changed that and no errors now except one, it doesn't recognise the ,,Inserted"                                                                                       Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure triggerTransporturi, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "Inserted.id" could not be bound.

Comment: @Awesome, that was the point of my comment. You should have a join on inserted table.

Comment: Updated answer to use join instead, wasn't thinking about that at the time. Honestly, the whole trigger needs to be rewritten. This should at least fix the problem. You will want to structure your other `update` so it is similar to this one too.

Comment: Cool. Could you upvote and accept this answer then? I'm not sure why it was ever downvoted.

Comment: @gmiley, I downvoted it because it had errors. Now I will take back.